# XCode 4.5 quit unexpectedly ASSERTION FAILURE

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

My XCode crashes and crashes and crashes and i can't open my project here is the error that i receive

```
Process:         Xcode [883]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.5 (1839)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-1839000000000000~3
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 10747437
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [110]

Date/Time:       2012-10-04 14:53:34.748 +0300
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G56)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          2021 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           9
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  358 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   9
Anonymous UUID:                      E9E2BB86-81A1-404E-90D8-B7F32880697C

Crashed Thread:  13  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4G182
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFoundation/IDEFoundation-1877/Framework/Classes/Model/SourceControl/IDESourceControlWorkspaceMonitor.m:1054
Details:  Attempted to add repository (IDESourceControlRepository) Name:192.168.1, Type:Subversion, Location:svn://192.168.1.20 when (IDESourceControlRepository) Name:192.168.1, Type:Subversion, Location:svn://192.168.1.20 already existed.
Object:   <IDESourceControlWorkspaceMonitor: 0x402515500>
Method:   -_findWorkingTreesForFilePath:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x402c1fe40>{name = (null), num = 11}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010e6ad7ef -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010d9752a5 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010e20bcfd __block_global_5 (in IDEFoundation)
  3  0x00007fff922a3ae1 -[NSBlockOperation main] (in Foundation)
  4  0x00007fff9226a6b4 -[__NSOperationInternal start] (in Foundation)
  5  0x00007fff9227d912 ____NSOQSchedule_block_invoke_2 (in Foundation)
  6  0x00007fff8c619a82 _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
  7  0x00007fff8c61a961 _dispatch_worker_thread2 (in libdispatch.dylib)
  8  0x00007fff937ac3da _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_c.dylib)
  9  0x00007fff937adb85 start_wqthread (in libsystem_c.dylib)

objc[883]: garbage collection is ON
abort() called

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b25c27d CFAllocatorDeallocate + 221
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b28b4c6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
2   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff88a1a2bf RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 277
3   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff88a214bf ReceiveNextEventCommon + 181
4   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff88a213fa BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a013779 _DPSNextEvent + 659
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a01307d -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 135
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a00f9b9 -[NSApplication run] + 470
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a28beac NSApplicationMain + 867
9   com.apple.dt.Xcode              0x000000010d8e6d17 0x10d8e5000 + 7447
10  com.apple.dt.Xcode              0x000000010d8e6ca8 0x10d8e5000 + 7336

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: IDE Source Control Workspace Scanning Queue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89c1fbca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937ae2a6 _pthread_cond_wait + 890
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff922aba5c -[NSCondition waitUntilDate:] + 371
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9227522e -[NSConditionLock lockWhenCondition:beforeDate:] + 251
4   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e20b782 __block_global_3 + 1154
5   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e172d00 -[IDESourceControlManager remoteRootPathForFilePath:sourceControlExtension:completionBlock:] + 1277
6   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e16378a -[IDESourceControlManager workingTreeRootForFilePath:sourceControlExtension:completionBlock:] + 1591
7   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e1633fc -[IDESourceControlManager workingTreeRootForFilePath:sourceControlExtension:completionBlock:] + 681
8   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e11aa99 -[IDESourceControlManager workingTreeRootForFilePath:completionBlock:] + 130
9   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e20b2f3 __65-[IDESourceControlWorkspaceMonitor _findWorkingTreesForFilePath:]_block_invoke_0 + 602
10  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e1c0a3e __66-[IDESourceControlManager workingTreeForFilePath:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_0426 + 1411
11  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff922a3ae1 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 116
12  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e159232 -[IDESourceControlManager performRequest:waitUntilFinished:withCompletionBlock:] + 761
13  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e172b47 -[IDESourceControlManager remoteRootPathForFilePath:sourceControlExtension:completionBlock:] + 836
14  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e16378a -[IDESourceControlManager workingTreeRootForFilePath:sourceControlExtension:completionBlock:] + 1591
15  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e1196b6 -[IDESourceControlManager workingTreeForFilePath:completionBlock:] + 811
16  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e119583 -[IDESourceControlManager workingTreeForFilePath:completionBlock:] + 504
17  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e11916f -[IDESourceControlWorkspaceMonitor _findWorkingTreesForFilePath:] + 268
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c619a82 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 18
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c61b2d2 _dispatch_queue_drain + 264
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c61b12e _dispatch_queue_invoke + 54
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c61a928 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 198
22  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937ac3da _pthread_wqthread + 316
23  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937adb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89c207e6 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c61b786 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 923
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c61a316 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89c20192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937ac594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937adb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.low-priority
0   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff92228893 _NSResolveSymlinksInPathUsingCache + 857
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff922283f9 -[NSString(NSPathUtilities) _stringByResolvingSymlinksInPathUsingCache:] + 124
2   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e1150e3 -[NSString(IDEIndexAdditions) ideIndex_stringByResolvingSymlinksInPath] + 54
3   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e112606 +[IDEIndexingEngine runLoadJob:] + 315
4   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e135e0b -[IDEIndexingJob run] + 99
5   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e25c0fa __40-[IDEIndexingJobScheduler _scheduleJobs]_block_invoke_0 + 31
6   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010d998d20 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke_0 + 16
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c619a82 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 18
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c61a961 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 255
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937ac3da _pthread_wqthread + 316
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937adb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89c1e6b6 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c61d0c4 _dispatch_group_wait_slow + 91
2   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e20ae12 __51-[IDESourceControlWorkspaceMonitor _startScanTimer]_block_invoke_0 + 65
3   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010d999370 __DVTDispatchSourceSetEventHandler_block_invoke_0 + 16
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c61e497 _dispatch_source_invoke + 649
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c61b13f _dispatch_queue_invoke + 71
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c61a928 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 198
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937ac3da _pthread_wqthread + 316
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937adb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89c1e67a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89c1dd71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b28350c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b28bc74 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b28b486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff92287fd7 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 335
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9227c72a -[NSThread main] + 68
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9227c6a2 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937aa8bf _pthread_start + 335
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937adb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89c1fdf2 __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b2d4c8b __CFSocketManager + 1355
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937aa8bf _pthread_start + 335
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937adb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89c1e67a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89c1dd71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b28350c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b28bc74 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b28b486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.DTDeviceKit           0x00000001159b5cff -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 298
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9227c72a -[NSThread main] + 68
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9227c6a2 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937aa8bf _pthread_start + 335
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937adb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89c20192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937ac594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937adb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89c1e67a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89c1dd71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b28350c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b28bc74 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b28b486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9222df7b -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 267
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9222de67 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 62
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9227c72a -[NSThread main] + 68
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9227c6a2 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937aa8bf _pthread_start + 335
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937adb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937adb78 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89c20192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937ac594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937adb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 13 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89c1fce2 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937ac7d2 pthread_kill + 95
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff9379da7a abort + 143
3   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010e6ad25f +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:] + 596
4   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010d9752a5 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 128
5   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e20bcfd __block_global_5 + 696
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff922a3ae1 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 116
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9226a6b4 -[__NSOperationInternal start] + 705
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9227d912 ____NSOQSchedule_block_invoke_2 + 124
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c619a82 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 18
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c61a961 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 255
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937ac3da _pthread_wqthread + 316
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937adb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 14:: CVDisplayLink
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89c1fbca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937ae2a6 _pthread_cond_wait + 890
2   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff888401cb CVDisplayLink::waitUntil(unsigned long long) + 279
3   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8883f631 CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 559
4   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8883f3e9 _ZL13startIOThreadPv + 148
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937aa8bf _pthread_start + 335
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937adb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89c1e67a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89c1dd71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b28350c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b28bc74 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b28b486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff8bf082f2 _ZL20SpotlightQueryThreadPv + 434
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937aa8bf _pthread_start + 335
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937adb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89c1fe42 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff93760dea nanosleep + 164
2   com.apple.CoreSymbolication     0x00007fff87df23bb cleaner_thread_main(void*) + 42
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937aa8bf _pthread_start + 335
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff937adb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 13 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000006  rcx: 0x00000001177159e8  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x000000000000f023  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x0000000117715a10  rsp: 0x00000001177159e8
   r8: 0x00007fff78532fb8   r9: 0x00007f944651aee0  r10: 0x00007fff89c1fd0a  r11: 0xffffff80002dad60
  r12: 0x0000000402c4afb8  r13: 0x00007fff87cf9e80  r14: 0x0000000117716000  r15: 0x0000000117715b18
  rip: 0x00007fff89c1fce2  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x0000000101adc000
Logical CPU: 0

Binary Images:
       0x10d8e5000 -        0x10d8e7fff  com.apple.dt.Xcode (4.5 - 1839) <B5C20A97-D031-383A-8045-814DBC82546E> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
       0x10d8f3000 -        0x10dc0eff7  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation (4.5 - 1828) <EBED7760-2AF1-325D-AA67-308E33DF1EEF> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation


External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 13
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 2591
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=277.5M resident=162.0M(58%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=115.5M(42%)
Writable regions: Total=17.2G written=33.8M(0%) resident=96.8M(1%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=17.1G(99%)

REGION TYPE                        VIRTUAL
===========                        =======
CG backing stores                    5492K
CG image                              152K
CG raster data                        684K
CG shared images                     4432K
CoreAnimation                         316K
CoreGraphics                           16K
CoreImage                              24K
CoreServices                         1424K
IOKit                                11.4M
JS JIT generated code                   8K
JS JIT generated code (reserved)      1.0G        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
MALLOC                              384.8M
MALLOC (reserved)                    15.8G        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
MALLOC guard page                      80K
Memory tag=240                          4K
Memory tag=242                         12K
Memory tag=243                          4K
Memory tag=249                        156K
Memory tag=251                         68K
OpenCL                                 52K
OpenGL GLSL                          1024K
SQLite page cache                     960K
STACK GUARD                          56.1M
Stack                                15.7M
VM_ALLOCATE                          17.5M
__CI_BITMAP                            80K
__DATA                               29.8M
__IMAGE                               528K
__LINKEDIT                           64.7M
__TEXT                              212.8M
__UNICODE                             544K
mapped file                          82.5M
shared memory                        17.3M
===========                        =======
TOTAL                                17.6G
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space      908.3M

Model: Macmini5,1, BootROM MM51.0077.B10, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.3 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.76f0
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 384 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353737334348532D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353737334348532D4348392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xE4), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.198.19.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.8f17, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK5065GSXF, 500.11 GB
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 3
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8281, 0xfa113000 / 6
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: USB Mouse, 0x09da  (A-FOUR TECH CO., LTD.), 0x000a, 0xfd120000 / 5
USB Device: Keyboard Hub, apple_vendor_id, 0x1006, 0xfd130000 / 4
USB Device: Apple Keyboard, apple_vendor_id, 0x0221, 0xfd132000 / 6
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

I tried removing xcuserdata folder from .xcodeproj file that didn't worked

I tried removing the project from repository in XCode -> Organizer

I tried removing the derived project data that

I really don't know what the problem is, we are using a SVN server on the network so we can sync the sources of the projects.

Comment: Is it just one project it's crashing on? Does it work fine with other projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good chance that is fixed in Xcode 4.5.1:

> Source Control
>
> Issues interacting with working copies known by the Xcode app. 12364258, 12389205, 12389198

The release notes are available on the Apple Developer Download site ([here](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.5.1/release_notes_xcode_4.5.1.pdf)); they don't appear to be updated on the main Apple Developer website.

Answer (score 0):

```
Details:  Attempted to add repository (IDESourceControlRepository) Name:192.168.1, Type:Subversion, Location:svn://192.168.1.20 when (IDESourceControlRepository) Name:192.168.1, Type:Subversion, Location:svn://192.168.1.20 already existed.
```

I would remove all your repositories from Xcode and add them again.

Comment: I removed the project from repositories from organizer, same problem !

Comment: @MykeAndreas I would update to Xcode 4.5.1 like what trojanfoe said and see if the problem stays or not.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Xcode 4.5.1 and just started having this problem today. The app was running in the simulator and then the simulator started acting funny so I decided to stop everything and close Xcode. I had to blast it. When I tried to relaunch I got this error and cannot launch anymore. Clearly something got messed up.